# ASP.NET core 1.1 HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, identityserver4, asp.net-core-1.1

When I try and startup my ASP.NETcore 1.1 on my server I get the error:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Common causes of this issue:
>
> The application process failed to start The application process
>   started but then stopped The application process started but failed to
>   listen on the configured port

I checked the event viewer.

> Application: MyApp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException at MyApp.Program.Main(System.String[])

`MyApp.Program.Main` is

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "IdentityServer";

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

This is based on the Identity Server 4 code.

`Stdout` has

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=1.1.0.0

I have added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting via NuGet to my project. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll` is in my published files...

After doing some more digging I found this post [Can't load Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 1.1.0.0 #1826](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1826). It suggests to remove `app.AddBrowserLink();`. `AddBrowserLink()` is not used at all in my code.

By commenting out code the error seems to come when I reference a project that is not .NET Core based that depends on traditional .NET.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hansleman had the answer from his post [How to reference an existing .NET Framework Project in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web App](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx).

[image: ASPNET]

I had created an ASP.NET Core 1.1 app pointing to .NET Core.
I recreated my website as ASP.NET Core 1.1 and had it point to .NET Framework and then the code that was failing ran.